# HTML5 video tag (available sources)

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

Since YouTube is not a usable "src" for the HTML video tag, are there any alternative websites which offer hosting for free that can be used here?

```
<video id="video">
<source type="video/mp4" src="www.YouTube.co.uk">
</video>
```

I've read that google drive has worked previously, however I'm unsure as to how I can input a direct link to the media file.

I believe this is because google drive now uses the YouTube API for streaming video.

Please see the following link, about google drive as a media source: https://sourcey.com/html5-video-streaming-from-google-drive/

Thanks

**My requirements for this are:**

1. My client doesn't have a hosting package with enough bandwidth &
   storage to allow for over 3,000+ views of media files.
2. I need to check that the user has watched the entire video; the entire length, without skipping and pausing parts. Using events.

Comment: Are there any major reason's why you can't embed a youtube video? I don't image there are many free video hosts that match your requirements.

Comment: Branding overlays are of issue for the client. They deem YouTube to present an unprofessional theme of which the web platform should not contain. - it baffles me . If this is the case, they should opt for better hosting. But I don't get to make this decision unfortunately

Comment: Free providers tend to want to have their branding over the video, otherwise they can't make any money from the hosting. An alternative might be to host the video on a separate host that offers high bandwidth or a CDN.